How to extract fontSize information from WebViews in Accessibility Service?
I am building a Accessibility Service app in android, I need to extract the font Size of the opened app elements.
I am able to fetch the font size for all the cases except WebViews using the ExtraRenderInfo
AccessibilityNodeInfo.ExtraRenderingInfo eri = null;
eri = node.getExtraRenderingInfo();
if(eri != null) {
  float fontSize = 0;
  fontSize = node.getExtraRenderingInfo().getTextSizeInPx();
  jsonWriter.name("textSizeInPx").value(fontSize);
}

is there a way to extract fontSize for TextView located inside WebView, is that a possibility? Also, to add I have zero control on the app which is having WebView or the actual WebView url. Only thing I can play/experiment is the AccessibilityService App.
TIA
